# Problem compiling node with Geany

Tags: ros, ide, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone when i compile my Node;cpp file it points me towards an error in Node.h file
And the error it shows is

Node.h : fatal error: ros/ros.h : No file or folder of this type

I have looked into previous questions asked on this topic, so my file "package.xml" and "CmakeLists.txt" for this node seems correct to me, though i am posting them

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>p_sedimentation_estimator</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>Fusion of pointcloud sonar and scan laser</description>

  <maintainer email="ro@rob.com">Rob</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>cana_msgs</build_depend>

  <!-- todo -->

  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->

  </export>
</package>
```

Cmakelists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(p_sedimentation_estimator)

add_definitions(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED
    roscpp
    std_msgs
    geometry_msgs
    pcl_conversions
    pcl_ros
    tf2_ros
    tf2_bullet
    cana_msgs
)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES p_sedimentation_estimator
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS other_catkin_pkg
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5Core)
find_package(Boost 1.54.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS )


###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

file(GLOB Node_SRC
    "src/*.h"
    "src/*.cpp"
)

## Declare a C++ executable
add_executable(p_sedimentation_estimator ${Node_SRC})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(p_sedimentation_estimator
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}
  Qt5::Core
)

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
install(TARGETS p_sedimentation_estimator p_sedimentation_estimator
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

WHAT or Where could be the problem ??

1)catkin_make runs without error

2)Compilation of the node.cpp program gives this error(Node.h : fatal error: ros/ros.h : No file or folder of this type) in node.h file

3. is it necesarry to use build also , other than sourcing, catkin_make and compiling.

Help Needed :)
Thanku in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345572/problem-compiling-node-with-geany/) by [Yadav](https://answers.ros.org/users/50582/yadav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-03-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-02**:
Could I ask you to please format your questions properly? I've done it for you now (and in your previous questions as well), but for next time: select any code/console text/etc and press `ctrl+k` or click the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it).

**Comment by [Yadav](https://answers.ros.org/users/50582/yadav/) on 2020-03-02**:
@gvdhoorn Thanku so much...i will keep it in mind next time :)

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-03-02**:
@Yadav If I understand your question correctly, at the end you specify three points 1), 2), 3) that you step through, right?

Could you please explain how you "compile" your node? Because this is actually what `catkin_make` will do for you and thus I don't think you can have 1) successfull and 2) not if you are using the standard workflow...

**Comment by [Yadav](https://answers.ros.org/users/50582/yadav/) on 2020-03-02**:
@mgruhler
Yes,catkin_make runs without error
But when i compile the code in the Node.cpp file alone, using "Geany" it shows me the error(Node.h : fatal error: ros/ros.h : No file or folder of this type) in node.h file
So by catkin_make it gets compiled but it doen't work according to the code in Node.cpp file

Standard workflow ?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-03-03**:
@Yadav then you don't have a problem with compiling your code in general, but only using geany.
I've retagged and reworded your question title as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As ROS and `caktin` heavily builds on `CMake` as a build system, you at least need an IDE that supports it.
Even though [it is stated](https://wiki.geany.org/howtos/configurebuildmenu) that Geany can use `CMake`, I haven't found a way to properly configure it with a few minutes of search. You might have to use some plugins.

This is even more true that ROS also requires a few more quirks to set up, usually.
There is a [large list of IDEs](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs) and how to use them with ROS on the wiki. I suggest you try one of those if you want to compile from source. If you want more fancy stuff like jumping to external (out of your source) function definitions, those instructions might come in handy.

On another note: you tagged your question with `Indigo`. Indigo [is EOL since for almost a year now](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions), I suggest to update to a new one

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yadav](https://answers.ros.org/users/50582/yadav/) on 2020-03-10**:
I could suggest to not use GEANY also :) Thanks @mgruhler @gvdhoom  for the help :)